# Reading and writing from pipe after execvp using dup2

Tags: c, exec, stdout, execvp, dup2

I want to execute a process called "left" which basically gets 2 integer by scanf and prints its sum. So as to get the sum, i redirected the stdout and stdin by using 1 pipe. But scanf doesn't read anything and blocks the process. What's wrong here?

```
        num2 = 1;
        int filed[2];
        pipe(filed);
        dup2(filed[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup2(filed[0],STDIN_FILENO);
        
        printf("%d\n%d\n",num1,num2); // sending the numbers
        int fide =fork();
        if (fide == 0)
        {
            char *args[] = {"./left",NULL};
            execvp("./left",args);
            
        }
        else
        {
            
            wait(NULL);
            
            close(filed[1]);
            char buf[11];
            read(filed[0],buf,11);
            fprintf(stderr,"my result: %s \n",buf);
           
        }
```

Comment: You should take a look at [Intercommunicating using stdin and stdout between forked C processes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78210667/15168).  It appears it was asked by someone else taking your course.

Comment: You are not attempting to connect a pipe (or something) to the standard input of the child; that won't happen magically. You probably need a second pipe to get the answer back from the child; you'll need to sort that plumbing out. Writing to the process's standard output won't send the message to the child's standard input, and it will likely be flushed before the `fork()`. Note that the conventional way of calling `execvp()` would be `execvp(args[0], args);`. Your code does not handle `execvp()` failing; it should, even if that's only `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`, but print an error message first.

Comment: My previous comment was partially correct — but I missed the `dup2()` operations, so I didn't help as much as all that. Those operations are not what's needed.  You've connected the standard output of the initial process to the write end of the pipe; you've connected the standard input of the initial process to the read end of the pipe.  Pipes are unidirectional — it isn't a good idea to try using one pipe for both reading and writing between two processes.  You need two pipes: one to write to the child, one to read from the child.  The parent process should not wreck its own standard I/O.

Comment: You want two channels of communication (one from parent to child, and one from child to parent), but you only created one pipe. /// The read end of the pipe 1 exists as Parent's fd 0, Parent's 3, Child's fd 0 and Child's fd 3. It should only exist as Child's fd 0. /// The write end of the pipe 1 exists as Parent's fd 1, Parent's 4, Child's fd 1 and Child's fd 4. It should only exist as Parent's fd 4. /// The read end of the pipe 2 should only exist as Parent's fd 5. /// The write end of the pipe2 should only exist as Child's fd 2.

Comment: [continued] To ensure the above, you need to place the `dup2` calls as the appropriate place to avoid creating addition fds in the wrong process, and close the extra fds.

Comment: The parent will write on the 'to child write' file descriptor — possibly using POSIX [`dprintf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dprintf.html) or more likely using `sprintf()` and `write()`.  It will read output from the child on the 'from child' file descriptor.  That will have to be done with `read()`; there is no `dscanf()`.  The parent should close file descriptors it won't use.  The child should close unused file descriptors too.  Note that `dup2()` does not close the file descriptor that is duplicated, only the one it is duplicated to.

Comment: **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the original file descriptors from `pipe()` as soon as possible. In particular, that means before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions. The rule also applies with either `dup()` or [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) with `F_DUPFD`.